Wrong drawing style in repeatable function in C++
I create a programm in C++ to convert an input expression to postfix expression then visualize it out under a binary tree (you can use arrow key to move the graph and press SPACE to go back to menu window). I also create a simple menu to let user choose whether to use available expression file or enter a new expression by themselves.
The problem is, after I choose 1 option, the program execute and visualize the expression out normally. But after that if I return to the menu and choose to visualize another expression, the format of the binary tree isn't like what I expected (small font, missing line between Nodes and missing circle border of each Node)
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

#include <graphics.h>

#define E exp(1)
#define Pi M_PI
using namespace std;

struct tNode{
    string data;
    tNode *pLeft, *pRight;
};

tNode *root;

tNode *newNode(string data){
    tNode *node = new tNode();
    node->data = data;
    node->pLeft = NULL;
    node->pRight = NULL;
    return node;
}

// Check  

int heightOfTree(tNode *root){
    if(root==NULL) return 0;
    int height = 1;
    if(root->pLeft==NULL and root->pRight==NULL) return 1;
    return 1 + max(heightOfTree(root->pLeft), heightOfTree(root->pRight));
}


//Read tree follow the order Left node - Middle Node - Right Node
void LNR(tNode *root){
    if(root!=NULL){
        if(root->pLeft != NULL) LNR(root->pLeft);
        if(root!=NULL){
            cout << root->data << " ";
        }
        if(root->pRight != NULL) LNR(root->pRight);
    }
}

void convert_to_char(char* c, string s){
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        c += s[i];
    }
    c[s.size()] = '\0';
}

int size(char *c){
    int i = 0;
    while(c[i] != NULL){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int isdigit(char c){
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isoperator(string c){
    if(c == "+" || c == "-" || c == "*" || c == "/" || c == "^" || c == "%" || c == "^") return 1;
    return 0;
}

int isspecial(string s){
    if(s == "ln" || s == "log"  || s == "abs" || s == "cos" || s == "sin" || s == "tan" || s == "cot" || s == "acos" || s == "asin" || s == "atan" || s == "acot" || s == "cosh" || s == "sinh" || s == "tanh" || s == "coth" || s == "sqrt" || s == "cbrt")
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pri(string c){
    if(c == "+" || c == "-") return 1;
    if(c == "%") return 2;
    if(c == "*" || c == "/") return 3;
    if(c == "^") return 4;
    if(c == "ln" || c == "log"  || c == "abs" || c == "cos" || c == "sin" || c == "tan" || c == "cot" || c == "acos" || c == "asin" || c == "atan" || c == "acot" || c == "cosh" || c == "sinh" || c == "tanh" || c == "coth" || c == "sqrt" || c == "cbrt") return 5;
    return 0;
}

int pric(char c){
    if(c == '+' || c == '-') return 1;
    if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%') return 2;
    if(c == '^') return 3;
    return 0;
}

int isoperatorc(char c){
    if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '^' || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '%') return 1;
    return 0;
}

double s_to_double(string x){               //string -> double
    if(x == "e") return E;
    if(x == "pi") return Pi;
    
    double tmp = 0;
    string::iterator it = x.begin();
    
    while(*it != '.' && it != x.end()){
        tmp = tmp * 10 + (*it - 48);
        it++;
    }
    if(it == x.end()) return tmp;
    
    double a = 0;
    it = x.end() - 1;
    while(*it != '.'){
        a = (a + (*it - 48.0)) /  10;
        it--;
    }
    tmp += a;
    
    return tmp;
}

void put(char* s, queue<string> &q, stack<string> &st){         // convert expression from string to queue
    for(int i = 0; i < size(s);i++){                        // Suffix expression stored in q, operator store in st
        if(s[i] == ' ') continue;
        else if(isdigit(s[i])){                             // Read number
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            while(isdigit(s[i + 1])){
                i++;
                tmp += s[i];
            }
            if(s[i + 1] == '.'){
                tmp += s[++i];
                while(isdigit(s[i + 1])){
                    i++;
                    tmp += s[i];
                }
            }
            q.push(tmp);
        }
        else if(s[i] == '('){                               // Read open bracket
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            st.push(tmp);
        }
        else if(s[i] == ')'){                               // Read close bracket
            while(!st.empty() && st.top() != "("){
                q.push(st.top());
                st.pop();
            }
            if(!st.empty()) st.pop();
        }
        // Read special function
        else if(s[i] == 'l' && s[i + 1] == 'n'){
            i++;
            string s = "ln";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'l' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 'g'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "log";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'b' && s[i + 2] == 's'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "abs";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 's'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "cos";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'i' && s[i + 2] == 'n'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "sin";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 't' && s[i + 1] == 'a' && s[i + 2] == 'n'){
            i+=2;
            string s = "tan";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 't'){
            i += 2;
            string s = "cot";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 's' && s[i + 2] == 'i' && s[i+3] == 'n'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "asin";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'c' && s[i + 2] == 'o' && s[i+3] == 's'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "acos";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 't' && s[i + 2] == 'a' && s[i+3] == 'n'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "atan";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'c' && s[i + 2] == 'o' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "acot";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'i' && s[i + 2] == 'n' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "sinh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 's' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "cosh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 't' && s[i + 1] == 'a' && s[i + 2] == 'n' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "tanh";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 't' && s[i+3] == 'h'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "coth";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 's' && s[i + 1] == 'q' && s[i + 2] == 'r' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "sqrt";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'c' && s[i + 1] == 'b' && s[i + 2] == 'r' && s[i+3] == 't'){
            i += 3;
            string s = "cbrt";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'p' && s[i + 1] == 'i'){
            i++;
            string s = "pi";
            st.push(s);
        }
        else if(isoperatorc(s[i])){
            start:
            if(st.empty() || st.top() == "("){
                string tmp;
                
                tmp += s[i];
                st.push(tmp);
                continue;
            }
            else if(pric(s[i]) > pri(st.top())){
                string tmp;
                tmp += s[i];
                st.push(tmp);
            }
            else{
                q.push(st.top());
                st.pop();
                goto start;
            }
        }
        else{
            string tmp;
            tmp += s[i];
            q.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    while(!st.empty()){
        q.push(st.top());
        st.pop();
    }
    
    queue<string> Q = q;
    while(!Q.empty()){
        cout << Q.front() << " ";
        Q.pop();
    }
}

tNode* makeExpression(queue<string> q){
    stack<tNode*> stackNode;
    while(!q.empty()){
        if(isoperator(q.front())){
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            P->pRight = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            
            P->pLeft = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
        else if(isspecial(q.front())){
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            P->pRight = stackNode.top();
            stackNode.pop();
            P->pLeft = NULL;
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
        else{
            
            tNode* P = newNode(q.front());
            
            stackNode.push(P);
            q.pop();
        }
    }
    return stackNode.top();
}


// Function to draw a binary tree recursively

int childCount(struct tNode* root){
    int x=0,y=0;
    if(root->pLeft == NULL && root->pRight == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }else   
    {
        
        if(root->pRight !=NULL && root->pLeft==NULL){
            x = 1 + childCount(root->pRight);
        }
        
        if(root->pLeft != NULL){
            x = 1+ childCount(root->pLeft);
        }
        if(root->pRight != NULL){
            y = 1+ childCount(root->pRight);
        }

        if(x >= y){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return y;
        }
    }
}




/*Code  fixed*/
//check neu la ve node sau thang xuong thi check = 0, con binh thuong check = 1
//check if following node is drawn straight down, check = 0, else check = 1

void drawTree(struct tNode* root, int x, int y, int xOffset, int level, int check) {

    if (root != NULL) {
        // Draw left subtree       
        int xOffset_1 = xOffset*check;        
        if(root -> pRight != NULL && root -> pLeft == NULL){
            // Draw when node has only 1 child node
//          delay(1000);
            line(x,y,x,y+80);

            drawTree(root->pRight, x, y+80, xOffset, level+1, 0); // if xOffset = 0 the following childNode will be place above each other
            
            
        }else{      
        if (root->pLeft != NULL) {
            int cntLeft = childCount(root->pLeft);
            
            if (level == 0 ){
//              delay(1000);
                line(x, y, x - xOffset*cntLeft, y + 80);
                drawTree(root->pLeft, x - xOffset*cntLeft, y + 80, xOffset, level + 1, 1 );
            }
            else
            {
//              delay(1000);
                line(x, y, x - xOffset*cntLeft, y + 80);    
                drawTree(root->pLeft, x - xOffset*cntLeft, y + 80, xOffset, level + 1, 1);
    
            }
        }
        // Draw right subtree
        if (root->pRight != NULL) {
            int cntRight = childCount(root->pRight);
            
             if (level == 0 ){
//              delay(1000);
                line(x, y, x + xOffset*cntRight, y + 80);
                drawTree(root->pRight, x + xOffset*cntRight, y + 80, xOffset , level + 1, 1);
                
                

            } else{                 
//                  delay(1000);
                    line(x, y, x + xOffset*(cntRight), y + 80);
                
                    drawTree(root->pRight, x + xOffset*(cntRight), y + 80 , xOffset , level + 1 ,1);
                    
                
                

            }

        }
        
    }
    
    
        
        // Draw current node
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLUE);
        fillellipse(x, y, 33, 33);
        moveto(x - 10 - 6*(root->data.size() - 1), y - 10);
        char buffer[2]; buffer[1] = '\0';
        for(int i = 0; i < root->data.size(); i++) {
            buffer[0] = root->data[i];
            outtext(buffer);
        }
    }
}



void drawFunction(){
    //  Open graphic mode
    
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initwindow(1280,1600);
    
    int startX = 500, startY=50;
    int page =0;

    setlinestyle(CENTER_LINE, 0,3); // change line thickness
    settextstyle(4, HORIZ_DIR, 1); //change character size and font
    setbkcolor(BLUE);
    
//  Create a binary tree
    
    while(1){
        setactivepage(page);
        setvisualpage(1-page);
        setbkcolor(BLACK);
        cleardevice();
        setbkcolor(BLUE);
        drawTree(root, startX, startY, 50, 0, 1);

/*Use arrow key to move the graph, 
  Up_key to see upper part
  Down_key to see lower part
  Right_key to see right_part
  Left_key to see left_part
  SPACE to quit the graphic window and go back to the menu window*/
        
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
            startX -= 20; //Move the graph to the right
        }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
            startX += 20;  //Move the graph to the left
        }else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) ){
            
            startY +=20;   //Move the graph up
        }else if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
            startY -= 20;  //Move the graph down
        }else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)){
            break;
        }
        delay(10);
        page = 1 - page;
        
    }
    

  // Close graphics mode
    getch();
    
    
    closegraph();
}


void readDataFromFile(FILE *fptr)
{
    queue<string> q;
    stack<string> st;
    char expression[100];
       
    fgets(expression, 100, fptr);
    cout << expression << endl;
    put (expression, q, st);
        
    root = makeExpression(q);
    
    cout << "\nLNR: \n";
    LNR(root);
    
    drawFunction();
    return;
}

void enterExpression(){
    queue<string> q;
    stack<string> st;
    char c[1000];
    char expression[100];

    cout << "Enter Expression : ";
    getchar();
    gets(c); 

    cout << c << endl;
    put(c, q, st);

    root = makeExpression(q);   
    cout << "\nLNR: \n";
    LNR(root);

    drawFunction();
    
}


int main(){
    queue<string> q;
    stack<string> st;
    FILE *fptr;
    
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    
    char c[1000];
    char expression[100];
    int menu;
    
    
    int option = -1;
    int check;
    
//  colors(BLUE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 6);
        
    while(1){
        printf("\n\n-----Select the code file-----\n\n");
        printf("File-1: 3*atan(ln(7.54-8/344)*asin(64*log(7)))-7*6+cos(8-(9^67))\n");
        printf("File-2: cos(3*ln(pi)-9.6/77)-7*8+ln(6*4-32)\n");
        printf("File-3: atan(88)-9/sinh(34)+6*sqrt(7.78-cosh(78)) \n");
        printf("File-4: log(7.66-abs(ln(93)-6*7))+69.5/(3*6-sinh(83))\n");
        printf("\n9. Enter your own expression:\n");
        printf("0. Quit the program\n");
        printf("\n--------------------------------\n");
        printf("Enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        
        
        check = 0;
        switch (option){
            case 0:{
                check =1;
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                fptr = NULL;
                fptr = fopen("Input_expression_01.txt", "r");
                readDataFromFile(fptr); 
                            
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                fptr = NULL;
                fptr = fopen("Input_expression_02.txt", "r");
                readDataFromFile(fptr); 
                
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                fptr = NULL;
                fptr = fopen("Input_expression_03.txt", "r");
                readDataFromFile(fptr); 
                    
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                fptr = NULL;
                fptr = fopen("Input_expression_04.txt", "r");
                readDataFromFile(fptr); 
                    
                break;
            }
            case 9:{
                enterExpression();          
                break;
            }
            default: {
                printf("Invalid option\n"); 
                break;
            }
        }
        if( check == 1){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//cos(9.35*7-atan(6+ln(3^7)))*7-9/(7-533*7/(9-16*3))/(atan(7-ln(6^77))/9-acos(8*3.44)) 
// cos(7-9*6^7-6*atan(7-87))

Because I don't include .txt file here so I make an example that I input my own expression (image_01), and it visualize it out just like what I want (image_02). Then I press SPACE to quit graphic window and go back to menu. I choose to enter my own expression again and enter another expression (image_03), this time the error occur (image_04)
(the text size is smaller, missing line between nodes, missing border of each node)







What is a debugger?.

What is that "graphics.h"? Is it implementation of Borland's BGI API? The one somewhere from 1987? Implemented by whom and for what platform?

I'm using devC/C++  and graphic.h maybe Borland's BGI API (I got this library from my teacher)

My guess is that some setting is being changed and not reset before the next time you try to draw. It's a good idea to use fclose(filePtr) when you're done with a file. Setting the pointer to NULL is not enough.

I try adding fclose(fptr) in readDataFromFile() function, but the error still occur

@NguyễnHuyĐức, I have two questions: why do you re-implement the std::strlen() function through the size() function? Why do you implement a newNode() function, which erroneously take a string as a value instead of as a const lvalue or rvalue reference, if it is possible to write simply new tNode(data)? Your solutions are technically correct, but may lead to poor performance.

I also suggest not to check if c is a specific character by checking one at time, but store the sets of characters into a global array and then check simply std::find(std::begin(op_array), std::end(op_array), c) != std::end(op_array). It should improve both readability and maintainability.

Finally, if it is necessary to look for a sequence, like "log" or "cos", I suggest to use the std::find_if() or std::search() functions.
